# my Kakaotalk messenger program is working on Ubuntu with WiFi but not working on Ethernet connection

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, firewall, ethernet

When using my Kakaotalk messenger program it works on ubuntu with wifi, but is not working when using the Ethernet connection.

kakao talk is one of the messenger programs. 
Kakaotalk is not open when I just turn on my Ethernet connection. 
any one know the reason and the solution?

Ubuntu 19.10

 kakaotalk messenger program

Comment: just simplify that. I installed the window messenger program called 'Kakaotalk' on ubuntu 19.10 with wine. then this program is open with 'wireless' connection. but not opened with 'Ethernet' connection

Comment: I have been researching the Kakotalk, and I seen nothing, anywhere, where it says it can be used on an ethernet connection, only _mobile_. Sorry.

Comment: https://www.kakaocorp.com/service/KakaoTalk?lang=en

Comment: With the link you offered, click on Support on the top of the page, search for Ethernet. Results = 0 results. Etherent does not work with pinging towers.